# dns_get_record() is not returning all of the records

Tags: php, php-7.2, dns-get-record

I'm using PHP 7.2 in a virtual machine. Am using `dns_get_record()` function to get the DNS records but it is not returning all the records. When I'm using the same code on my local machine or any other online php code editor like 'phpfiddle.com', its returning desired output.

For example if I'm using `dns_get_record('google.com', DNS_ANY)` on my local server, it's returning 17 records but same code returns only 10 records on my VM.

Please help me with it. Am not even sure whether it is due to VM or some other reasons (may be any server config issue or something).

Have already tried `dns_get_record()` function with all possible combinations of parameters like `DNS_ANY` or '+' concatenated string of available constants like `DNS_A + DNS_AAAA + DNS_PTR + DNS_CNAME + ...` etc. but haven't met with desired output.

Comment: Don't use `DNS_ANY`, it's not a reliable mechanism because it just returns whatever happens to be cached, which might not be all the records. Request a specific record type and you should get good results.

Comment: @Barmar already did that. Used all the `DNS_` constants separately as well as their concatenated string, but didn't get valid results.

Comment: You can't concatenate them, you can only look for one type at a time.

Comment: `google.com` might not be a good name to test with. They use a CDN with dynamic load balancing, so you can get different results on different machines.